# undefined index for validation

Tags: php, validation

I am trying build a simple registration form with validation. When I leave a field blank and submit my form I keep getting this error undefined index email or undefined index password.For eg I fill in all fields except lastname I will get a notice saying email is undefined and if i fill all the fields I get username ,email and password is undefined. I googled it and the sugesstions i could get was `isset` , I tried using `isset` but it still does not work. Can anyone please help?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<style>
 label{
  width:100px;
  float:left;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
 session_start();
 $Firstname=isset($_SESSION['Firstname']);
 $Lastname=isset($_SESSION['Lastname']);
 $username=isset($_SESSION['username']);
 $email=isset($_SESSION['email']);
 $password=isset($_SESSION['password']);
 if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
 {

  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['Firstname'].'</p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['Lastname'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
   unset($_SESSION['error']);
 }
?>
<div class="signup_form">
<form action="registerUser.php" method="post" >
 <p>
  <label for="Firstname">First Name:</label>
  <input name="Firstname" type="text" id="Firstname" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="Lastname">Last Name:</label>
  <input name="Firstname" type="text" id="Lastname" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="username">User Name:</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30 "/>
 </p>
 <p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </p>
</form>
</div>
<p><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is registeruser.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //whether the username is blank
 if($_POST['FirstName'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['Firstname'] = " FirstName is required.";
 }
 if($_POST['LastName'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['Lastname'] = " LastName is required.";
 }
 //whether the email is blank
 if($_POST['email'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "E-mail is required.";
 }
 else
 {
  //whether the email format is correct
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']))
  {
   //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist
   $email= $_POST['email'];
  $personcon=$conn;  
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM TBLUSERS WHERE email = '$email'";
  $personinfo=oci_parse($personcon,$sql1);
   oci_execute($personinfo);
   oci_free_statement($personinfo);
   if (oci_num_rows($personinfo) > 0)
            {
    $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "This Email is already used.";
   }
  }

  else
  {
   //this error will set if the email format is not correct
   $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "Your email is not valid.";
  }
 }
 //whether the password is blank
 if($_POST['password'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Password is required.";
 }
 if($_POST['username'] == '')
 {
  $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "username is required.";
 }

  if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
 {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 else
 {
  $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
  $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $username=$_POST['$username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];


  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (FirstName,LastName,email, username,password) VALUES ('$FirstName', $LastName, '$email', '$username','$password')";
  $personinfo2=oci_parse($personcon,$sql2);
   oci_execute($personinfo2);
    oci_free_statement($personinfo2);
  if($personinfo2)
  {
   /* $from=praveen.mohan@students.mq.edu.au */
   $to = $email;
   $subject = "Confirmation from TutsforWeb to $username";
   $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb";
   $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";

   $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($sentmail)
            {
   echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
   }
   else
         {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
   }

  oci_close($personcon);
 }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: The first thing I'm seeing is that Firstname is sometimes FirstName and Lastname is sometimes LastName. It might not be the only problem but just play around with case sensitivity a bit.

Answer (score 2):

When you do not fill a field, its index will not exist in the `$_POST` associative array. You need to check with `isset` whether it exists like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');
$_SESSION['error'] = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //whether the username is blank
    if((!isset($_POST['FirstName'])) || ($_POST['FirstName'] == '')) {
        $_SESSION['error']['Firstname'] = " FirstName is required.";
    if((!isset($_POST['LastName'])) || ($_POST['LastName'] == '')) {
        $_SESSION['error']['Lastname'] = " LastName is required.";
    if((!isset($_POST['email'])) || ($_POST['email'] == '')) {
        $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "E-mail is required.";
    } else {
        //whether the email format is correct
        if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            //if it has the correct format whether the email has already exist
            $email= $_POST['email'];
            $personcon=$conn;  
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM TBLUSERS WHERE email = '$email'";
            $personinfo=oci_parse($personcon,$sql1);
            oci_execute($personinfo);
            oci_free_statement($personinfo);
            if (oci_num_rows($personinfo) > 0) {
                $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "This Email is already used.";
            }
        } else {
            //this error will set if the email format is not correct
            $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "Your email is not valid.";
        }
    }
    //whether the password is blank
    if((!isset($_POST['password'])) || ($_POST['password'] == '')) {
        $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Password is required.";
    }
    if((!isset($_POST['username'])) || ($_POST['username'] == '')) {
        $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "username is required.";
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username=$_POST['$username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (FirstName,LastName,email, username,password) VALUES ('$FirstName', $LastName, '$email', '$username','$password')";
        $personinfo2=oci_parse($personcon,$sql2);
        oci_execute($personinfo2);
        oci_free_statement($personinfo2);
        if($personinfo2) {
            /* $from=praveen.mohan@students.mq.edu.au */
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Confirmation from TutsforWeb to $username";
            $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb";
            $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn";

            $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

            if($sentmail) {
                echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
            } else {
                echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
            }

            oci_close($personcon);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

For example

```
((!isset($_POST['FirstName'])) || ($_POST['FirstName'] == ''))
```

will be `true` if there is no `'FirstName'` in `$_POST` or it is an empty string. The trick is that the second operand will not be checked if the first is true, preventing the problem you have mentioned in the question.

Further observations:

- your code assumes that there is a `$_SESSION['error']` element. You might get errors if this is not properly initialized
- your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
- your code is not properly structured, which makes it difficult to maintain
- your code mixes up sql with php, which is not elegant

Comment: tnx i will try to improve my code. But your solution did not work either it still say email is undefined on my index.php

Comment: @STRANGER, your code is unreadable, it is no wonder that something goes wrong. Bear with me, I will structure your code and see what the problem is.

Comment: @STRANGER, I have structured your code. As far as I can see, the problem was that you did not clear $_SESSION['error'], so in later instances, you will get the previous errors no matter what. I have reinitialized $_SESSION['error'] to make sure the code does not fail due to a previous error.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that your HTML input names don't match the PHP names you expect.

```
 if($_POST['FirstName'] == '') //Upper case N
```

While in the markup you use `<input name = "Firstname" ...` with lower case N

Another issue with the markup is two inputs are named Firstname:

```
<label for="Lastname">Last Name:</label>
<input name="Firstname" type="text" id="Lastname" size="30"/> <!--Firstname should be Lastname-->
```

Finally one more problem lies within the index.php file where you try to flash the session variable which comes back from the registerUser.php. Either there should be only one `$SESSION["error"]` or `isset(SESSION["error"]["field"])` must be used just like with the `$POST["field"]` in registerUser.php.

The flashing code would look like this after the change:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
   if (isset($_SESSION['error']['Firstname'])) echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['Firstname'].'</p>'; 
   if (isset($_SESSION['error']['Lastname'])) echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['Lastname'].'</p>';
   if (isset($_SESSION['error']['username'])) echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
   if (isset($_SESSION['error']['email'])) echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
   if (isset($_SESSION['error']['password'])) echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
   unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

I would also suggest looking up a good resource on the topic. Login/Register systems are hard to get right for the first time.